# Grid with negative margin (top) break my UI

Tags: material-ui

I have a live code illustration of the issue [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/l55wnmkvv9), as you can see, there is no space between the h1 and the Grid bellow (i was expecting 12px as i asked for a 24px spacing). If you open the console, you can see that a negative margin put the Grid above the h1, that's what i need to fix.

Am i doing something wrong here? What is the right way to patch it if i want the 24px spacing to be applied correctly with the h1?

I hope we don't have to encapsulate the h1 in a Grid container > Grid item itself.

Comment: I would just add `style={{marginTop: 24}}` to your grid container

Comment: If i start doing that kind of fix, why using the Grid component and not doing all the style with CSS?

Answer (score 11):

The `spacing` attribute sets the spacing between the `Grid` `items` inside the `Grid` `container`, but not between the `item` and `contaianer` sides. So, you end up with:

```
--------------------------
|----------    ----------| 
|| item   |<-->| item   ||
|----------    ----------|
|   ^              ^     | 
|   |              |     | 
|   v              v     | 
|----------    ----------| 
|| item   |<-->| item   ||
|----------    ----------| 
--------------------------
```

But the items are not offset from the sides of the container (depending on the `justify` and `alignItems|Content` values of course). This is accomplished by adding `padding` to the items and a negative `margin` to the container and adjusting the container `width`.

The easiest thing to do would be to add a `marginBottom` to the title style as shown [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/9low79w01o).

Because of the negative margin and width manipulation, nesting `Grid` containers can be tricky, though there are some [recommendations for how to deal with it](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/#nested-grid). For fine-control, I often set `spacing={0}` and use the [MUI spacing API](https://material-ui.com/system/spacing/) to implement the spacing between the items when nesting `Grid`s.

Comment: It worked like a charm. and behaved like you would expect. Thank you